# Different bundle identifier for an app in crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have two bundle identifier for an app and i want to add these in fabric crashlytics for two different bundles. Will i have to add for different bundles or fabric automatically create crash log for another(if any one bundle is added)?

Answer (score 1):

one bundleID means one App , so you  will have to add for different bundles , fabric doesnot automatically create crash log for other bundle Identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create multiple versions for the issue. Using [this way](https://www.buddybuild.com/blog/running-multiple-schemes-of-ios-apps) will help you much if you need adding more bundle ID in the future.